# What intent to start upon button click and how to count score in basic math app?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a very basic app where the user is supposed to provide a solution to a simple math problem. The math problem is for example 10+0= and the user is supposed to type in the sum of those two numbers. I'm stuck where the user has entered an answer and clicks the OK button. I know that I'm supposed to start some kind of intent here but I'm not sure what kind of intent? I want the app to be able to tell if the provided solution is the right or wrong answer to the math problem and, if right, add 1 to the current score (in the textview att the bottom) and display a new random math problem just like the one solved (or not solved).

**MathActivity.java**

```
public class MathActivity extends Activity {

private MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_math);

    //Media player with toggle button
    final ToggleButton togglesound = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglesound);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
    togglesound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (togglesound.isChecked()) {
                mp.start();
            } else {
                mp.pause();
            }   
        }
    });

    //Two random integers adding up to the sum of 10
    int min = 1;
    int max = 10;
    Random randomint = new Random();
    int randomint1 = randomint.nextInt(max - min +1) + min;
    int randomint2 = 10 - randomint1;
    //Displays random problem in textview
    TextView displayrandomproblem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvrandomproblem);
    displayrandomproblem.setText(randomint1 + " + " + randomint2 + " = ");

    //Fetches user answer and converts it to an integer
        EditText answer = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editanswer); {
        if (answer.getText().toString().length() > 0){
            int answerInt = Integer.parseInt(answer.getText().toString());
        }
    //Displaying a toast if no answer is provided
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your solution to the math problem!",
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
            }
    //When the OK button is clicked
        findViewById(R.id.btnok).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Submit user's answer
                Intent intent = new Intent();
        }});

}
    //Releasing media player on pause
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mp !=null) {
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
}
```

}

**activity_math.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/bg" >
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvheadline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="SPELA"
    android:textColor="@color/gul"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/togglesound"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textColor="@color/gul"
    android:textOn="Sound is on"
    android:textOff="Sound is off"
    android:text="ToggleButton" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvrandomproblem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editanswer"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvheadline"
    android:text="x + x ="
    android:textColor="@color/gul" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editanswer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvheadline"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvrandomproblem"
    android:ems="2"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textColor="@color/gul" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnok"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvrandomproblem"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:text="OK"
    android:textColor="@color/gul" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvcurrentscore"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvrandomproblem"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnok"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:text="Current score:"
    android:textColor="@color/gul"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Comment: can you tell me why we are using intent on click?Do you want to show score in next page?

Comment: I want to display the score on the bottom textview (tvcurrentscore) in the very same activity, directly below the OK button, so no, not @Kat-hat on the next page. When the user clicks the OK button, I want the score to be displayed and, in a perfect world, another math problem to show in a new view in the same activity. Alternatively, I can imagine having multiple math problems and edittexts for the user to submit his/hers answers, then the OK button and the current score.

Comment: @Kat-hat But for something to happen then the user clicks the OK button, I need to start an intent or am I wrong? I'm very new at this so I'm not sure what procedure is the right one or best one?

Comment: Instead of using intent for new question you can change the same activity textview(for new question)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you do not need to use an Intent. They are used only for interconnection between applications or for transferring data between activities.

As i understand, your application has single activity, so you just need to permanently increment value of textedit in the bottom

`EditText score = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tvcurrentscore);
score.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(score.getText) + 1))`

Comment: I see... so the button can submit the user's answer without an intent, only using the OnClickListener function, have I gotten that right?

Comment: Yes, you can call activity's methods from onClickListener.

Comment: I suggest to create method `generateTask()` and call it when user click OK button and he gives right answer